# What is the f(n) for this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

This is my open sequence, starting from index of $1$:

${0,3,2,15,4,5,8,12,13,9,10,29,27,17,25,20,18,33,21,57,40,51,34,36,44,...}$

I know some interesting properties about this sequence. When converted to binary, the count of unique non-null subsequences of the binary number equals it's index $i$.

By subsequences I mean this: a bitstring of 1101 has 9 unique (non-null) subsequences: 1, 0, 11, 10, 01, 101, 110, 111 and 1101. A bitstring of 101 has 6 of those, 111 and 10 have 3, etc.

Also, when taking the [$Fibonacci(n+3)-2$:nth](http://oeis.org/A001911) index, the binary representation is like [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A000975):

$a(0)=1_2=1$

$a(1)=10_2=2$

$a(3)=101_2=5$

$a(6)=1010_2=10$

$a(11)=10101_2=21$

$a(19)=101010_2=42$

How can I most simply calculate the $n$:th index of my sequence? For now, I have to programmatically test every binary number to get the count of subsequences, and compare it. While there are multiple roots for most of numbers (one notable is $f(n)=2^n-1$), in my series it is the lowest number whose binary expansion unique subsequence count matches.

Comment: Your sequence is not well-defined. There are multiple numbers who's binary expansion have exactly 9 subsequences, so which would be chosen?

Comment: I know there are multiple possible binary expansions, in this series I'm using the lowest possible number. One solution to this would be: $f(n)=2^n-1$, but this produces pretty large numbers. I edited the question to address this.

Comment: I believe your sequence should start $1, 3, 2, 15, 4, 5, 8, 12, 11, 9, 10, 23, 27, 17, 19, 20, 18, 33$. Regardless of whether you start with $0$ or $1$ (this is a matter of definition), your sequence has multiple real errors.

Comment: Maybe; I still think that 0 and 1 both pass, but 0 is smaller than 1. What are those errors you are talking about?

Comment: Compare our sequences. For example $11 < 13$, both have the same distinct subsequences but you have $13$ in your sequence.

Comment: Oh! You are right. Took me a while to find the main problem, and it was in side of my code (it removed the reversed representations of bits from candidates). I'll adjust the question a bit.

Comment: @hegez Could you show an example what you mean with the "subsequences" ?

Comment: @Peter by subsequences I mean this: a bitstring of 1101 has 9 unique (non-null) subsequences: 1, 0, 11, 10, 01, 101, 110, 111 and 1101. A bitstring of 101 has 6 of those, 111 has 3 (and so has 10), etc.